# Interpret stateParameter as BOOL type

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state parameter `show`, e.g

```
http://localhost/#/index?show=true
```

When I get that value from `$stateParams`, it was interpreted as string `true`, Now I'm converting the string to BOOL manually, e.g

```
if ($stateParams.show == 'true') {
    $scope.XXX = true;
}
```

Could it be done automatically?

Comment: There is no automatic way if you get the variable out of your URL as boolean, because it's ALWAYS a string. If you put your boolean into an stateParam, it will stay as a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are passing the parameter on the URL then i don't think there is an automatic way to do what you want. but you can do this.

don't pass the parameter on the url and add a default value to your parameter on your `state` definition like this.

```
$stateProvider.state("state1", {
        url: "/one",
        template: "<p>State 1 </p>",
        controller: "Ctrl1",
        params:{
          show:null
        }
      })
```

this will make the `show` parameter to stay as a `Boolean` as you change from one `state` to another.

checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Miqe/j4to216z/ pull out your console and see the difference between `state1` and `state2`